# Clustered Index - Trade-off Query VS Insert?

Tags: sql-server, database, clustered-index

I'm working on improving database performance of my application and now it comes to the part of clustered index. I don't have experience with it so I would like to ask.

**My application caveats**

In my application I have the concept of **Show**.

This means that a user can create/open a Show and then it will access only the objects related to that Show (Actors, clothes, items, etc).
So it is really commom to have queries using "*...WHERE ShowId = X*"

Also we do have quite a lot of inserts because of integrations (we have a job running daily that would get +/- 30k new rows to the database, all in the same Show) and deletions are not that commom... The user may delete a Show (which is really taking quite a long time).

The usage of the application is usually like:

- User creates a Show based on a "Master Show" (which copies a lot of data changing only the ShowId)
- User navigates around some screens to check this data
- User calls an algorithm that proccess the input of this show and generate a lot of outputs (30k+ inserts again, on the same show)
- User analyses these outputs

**The question**

Based on that, I thought that the best clustered key would be on [ ShowId, id ] for every table. But then, reading [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation, I have doubts **if this wouldn't make it worse given the number of inserts or if, because the inserts are made on the same ShowId, it would be ok**.

I don't have access to the PRD database nor to a copy of it for testing. I tested with the dev database but it is so small it didn't seem to have any impact at all.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Is more of a design question... What you didn't get?

Comment: What will be the rate of insert

Comment: It's quite high... The job and the algorithm runs in 5 minutes more or less... So 30k+ inserts / 5 minutes... The "Show creation" runs in seconds and generates something like 40k rows...

Comment: All indexes causes overhead on DML(insert,update,delete). You need to assess the performance gain on these actions is worth the overhead or not. So if your table is not overindexed and you gain performance advantage by having the indexes, it will not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you an answer without more information.  You should consider to post tables structure too.

It's true that for every index you add, you will generate an overhead on insert.  But if you need to use "WHERE SHOWID=..." you will have a strong positive impact for your SELECT in this case (on a large table, and considering SHOWID very selective, ie a few records over a lot of records of the whole table).

You said:

> "I don't have access to the PRD database nor to a copy of it for
>   testing. I tested with the dev database but it is so small it didn't
>   seem to have any impact at all."

But you can use execution plan to see how a query will use your index / table.  Moreover you could quite easily generate multiple random records to make your tests.